# Backbone Router initializes but dont fire the events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

I have a complex, multi level inherited app and i wanted to use Backbone.Router for navigation but it dont work as i expected.

The address of the application is not under root directory

**Like this:**
http://www.domain.com/App

and I wanted to use the BB's routing

Here is some code:

```
$(function () {
    var SayfaController = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "home", 
            "sayfa/:sayfaNo": "sayfa" 
        },
        initialize: function () {
          console.log('THIS WORKS');
        },
        home: function () {
           console.log('THIS DONT FIRE');
        },
        sayfa: function (sayfa) {
            console.log("NEITHER THIS FIRES");
            console.log(sayfa);
        }
    });

    var sayfaController = new SayfaController();

    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

    ....
});
```

initialize method works but 
The events wont fire when i click a link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/App/#/sayfa/6">Click</a>
```

or change the browser navigation bar

What am I doing wrong

Comment: get a 404 error with your link to the app

Comment: @kinakuta it was an example :) www.domain.com is not mine :)

Comment: is `Editor` the initial page? if the index page is `http://www.matbuu.bizim/` then home will run when run this url is visited. and `sayfa` will run when `http://www.matbuu.bizim#sayfa/123`. unless you've made modifications in using `#`

Comment: sorry for the confusion i edited the link

Comment: @ashley the initial page is http://www.domain.com/App/ I wanted to run the http://www.domain.com/App/#/sayfa/6 and get the 6 for parameter

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: remove the slash: domain.com/App/#sayfa/6

Comment: your saving your router instance to a variable and not using it. remove `var sayfaController` and just call `new SayfaController();`

Comment: @ashley i didnt get how this kind of call and assigning  can change the working mechanizm of a class?

Answer (score 0):

From a glance, it looks like you need to specify the root of your app, as it's not served from the root of your domain. See Backbone docs RE: Backbone.history:

> If your application is not being served from the root url / of your
>   domain, be sure to tell History where the root really is, as an
>   option: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:
>   "/public/search/"})

try `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/App/"});`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how to get it work for urls of kind

```
http://www.domain.com/App/#/sayfa/6
```

But for kind below it works.

```
http://www.domain.com/App#sayfa/6
http://www.domain.com/App
```

Use

```
 Backbone.history.start({
            root : "/App"
        });
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nEmeL/4/